# Create Datatable from DataGridView with ErrorText C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I have winform project that contains DataGridView control. I have to create Datatable from DataGridView. But i want to get cell's ErrorText message to Datatable also. Do datatable cells have an ErrorText message function? I am searching code something like below.

```
private void getErrorTexttoDT(DataGridView dgv,DataTable dt)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[i];
                if (cell.ErrorText.Length>0)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i][j].ErrorText = cell.ErrorText;// something like this.!!!!
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Is there any solution for that? Thanx.

[image]

Comment: [DataRow.SetColumnError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.setcolumnerror) + [DataRow.GetColumnsInError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.getcolumnsinerror)

Comment: @Jimi. thanx for your attention.I fixed now.It helped me.